# How to retrieve user data using query

Tags: android

I have a project app that user can ask a doctor for a schedule.

My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve patient data based on the chosen doctor and display it on the doctors profile in `ListView`, so thath the doctor can see patients request for a schedule when they log in.

Database

```
public class SqlDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_DOC = "doc_table";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_PATIENT = "patient_table";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "doc_db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String _id = "_id";
public static final String COL_REG_ID = "reg_id";
public static final String COL_DOC_CODE = "doc_code";
public static final String COL_FNAME = "firstname";
public static final String COL_LNAME = "lastname";
public static final String COL_SPEC = "specialty";
public static final String COL_CARD_ID = "card_id";
public static final String COL_REGION = "region";
public static final String COL_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String COL_CONTACT = "contact";
public static final String SCHED_MON = "monday";
public static final String SCHED_TUE = "tuesday";
public static final String SCHED_WED = "wednesday";
public static final String SCHED_THU = "thursday";
public static final String SCHED_FRI = "friday";
public static final String SCHED_SAT = "saturday";
public static final String SCHED_SUN = "sunday";
public static final String COL_PASS = "password";
public static final String COL_CONPASS = "confirm_password";
private static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE_DOC + " (" + _id
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_REG_ID
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_DOC_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_SPEC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CARD_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_REGION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LOCATION
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_MON
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_TUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_WED
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_THU + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_FRI
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_SAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_SUN
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONPASS
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public static final String id = "_id";
public static final String PAT_ID = "patient_id";
public static final String PAT_CARD_ID = "patient_cardid";
public static final String PAT_FNAME = "patient_firstname";
public static final String PAT_MNAME = "patient_middlename";
public static final String PAT_LNAME = "patient_lastname";
public static final String PAT_ADDRESS = "patient_address";
public static final String PAT_AGE = "patient_age";
public static final String PAT_DOB = "patient_dob";
public static final String PAT_BTYPE = "patient_bloodtype";
public static final String PAT_MEDALLERGY = "patient_medallergy";
public static final String PAT_MEDCOND = "patient_medcondition";
public static final String PAT_CONTACT = "patient_contact";
private static final String CREATE_PAT_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE_PATIENT + " (" + _id
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PAT_ID
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_CARD_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_FNAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_MNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_LNAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_AGE
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL. " + PAT_BTYPE
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_MEDALLERGY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + PAT_MEDCOND + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAT_CONTACT
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public SqlDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PAT_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_DOC);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_PATIENT);
    onCreate(db);
 }

}
```

Comment: anything from the logcat

Comment: nope, I don't know how to query my problem kind of new about querying and using SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this method in your SqlDbHelper class :

```
public ArrayList<String> getPatientNames(String docId) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String query = "Select * from  DATABASE_TABLE_PATIENT where _id ='"
            + docId+ "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                list.add(cursor.getString(3)+" "+cursor.getString(4)+" "+cursor.getString(5));
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                db.endTransaction();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}
```

The method above will return the list of names of all patient corresponding to the "_id" of the doctor passed to the method.

Now use this ArrayList of patient names in making an adapter for ListView:

```
SqlDbHelper obj = new SqlDbHelper(this);
ArrayList<String> patients = obj.getPatientNames(docId)   //Pass the doctor id here

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, patients);

listView.setAdapter(adapter); // Set this adapter to your listview
```

Comment: sir I did `String docId = textView.getText().toString;` and now I'm getting nullpointerexception at `ArrayList<String> patients = obj.getPatientNames(docId)`

Comment: It means your obj is having null. Have you written this line of code?
  `SqlDbHelper obj = new SqlDbHelper(this);`

Answer (score 2):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE NAME + " where "+ PAT_ID + "='" + user Id + "'";

SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getHandle();

cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);    
cursor.moveToLast();    
startManagingCursor(cursor);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {    
    do {    
        // do ....
        String id = cursor.getString(0);    
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());    
}
```